# Displaying Associated Data in View

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models, Examination and ExamFee. The relation between them is, examination has_one exam_fee and ExamFee belongs_to Examination. Here are the models:

```
class ExamFee < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :examination
end

class Examination < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :exam_fee
    has_many :exam_statuses
end
```

The association is working well without any problem. I can assign ExamFees to Examinations and they are working well when I check from Rails console. But,

In the **"app/views/examinations/index.html.erb"** I want to show (get associated exam fee data from ExamFee model for each examination) exam fees for each examination. How can I do this?

**app/views/examinations/index.html.erb File:**

```
<% @examinations.each do |examination| %>
<tr>
<td><%= examination.full_name %></td>
<td><%= examination.exam_date %></td>
<td><%= I WANT TO SHOW EXAMFEE FROM EXAM_FEE MODEL HERE %></td>
<td>Başvuru</td>
</tr>
<% end %>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: put your model code also so it will be easy to give an accurate solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure about your field name in database but you can try

```
examination.exam_fee.field_name
```

Comment: also i suggest to eager load the exam_fee model otherwise you will hit database repeatedly and do not forget to accept the answer